# How can I align text by width using python-docx library

Tags: python

I make some report document using `python-docx>=1.1.0` and I need to align text by width.
I don't understand which constant from `WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT` I should use.

I tried to user `WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.DISTRIBUTE` and all constants with prefix `JUSTIFY_` , but steel I can't to achieve my goal.

Comment: is there a specific width value or size or the width that you want to align to? such as a larger width on the left than the right? different alignments per sentence in the paragraph? how do you want the text to "align" ?

Comment: My manager told me: In the report we have block text of sentences. And I want these text will be formated by width in the same way if I would click the button "Justify text" in the Libre Office. Bu when I use WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.JUSTIFY in the my code I had different resutl when I clicked the button of Justify text in the Libre Office